# is there any input-process-output chart generate tools?

Tags: visualization

I can make a chart with any chart drawing tool, like 'LibreOffice Draw'. But I want to save the effort of drawing arrow-lines, blocks. Just give it the inputs, outputs and process name, then it will generate a chart for me. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I use [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) for this. You textually specify the graph you want and it provides a variety of command line tools for drawing it. It doesn't always draw things perfectly, but it usually does a good enough job. There are also probably LaTeX packages out there, if you're into that, although its probably overkill for your needs if you don't use it already.

Answer (score 2):

Graphviz will do this.  You define a graph using fairly simple text format and it will layout and draw the output.

[Graphviz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php)